# Why does libcurl calculate "4 TIMES" the number of added easy handles?

Tags: php, c, http, curl, libcurl

I have two questions.

(To downvoter: The second question is based on the recognization represented in the first question, so **these are NOT too broad**)

## Q1. What's the difference among `CURLOPT_MAXCONNECTS` / `CURLMOPT_MAXCONNECTS` / `CURLMOPT_MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS`?

I wrote the article:
[CURLOPT_MAXCONNECTS / CURLMOPT_MAXCONNECTS / CURLMOPT_MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS の違い - Qiita](http://qiita.com/mpyw/items/f011e28638c43c974e7a)

The summary in English is:

- `CURLOPT_MAXCONNECTS` (PHP 5.5 or later)

  - Limit of idle connections cached by `curl_exec`
- `CURLMOPT_MAXCONNECTS` (PHP 5.5 or later)

  - Limit of idle connections cached by `curl_multi_exec`
- `CURLMOPT_MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS` (PHP 7.0.7 or later)

  - Limit of active connections fired by `curl_multi_exec`

Are they correct?

## Q2. How does `CURLMOPT_MAXCONNECTS` work?

First, I believe that the description of `CURLMPOT_MAXCONNECTS` on current PHP Manual is wrong. I reported the issue here:
[PHP :: Doc Bug #72890 :: The description of CURLOPT_MAXCONNECTS is wrong](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72890)

> ### Description:
>
> The description of CURLOPT_MAXCONNECTS is wrong.
>
> PHP manual says: "Default is 10."
>   libcurl manual says: "By default libcurl will enlarge the size for each added easy handle to make it fit 4 times the number of added easy handles."

**<< MAIN QUESTION >>**

On the presumption that my opinion is correct, why does libcurl calculate **4 times** the number of added easy handles? I wonder this operation has no meaning...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The max connection options

You should probably read the documentation that curl provides if you want the most accurate and detailed documentation, as these options are simply passed through from PHP to libcurl. These three options are already documented quite clearly. If you have questions after having read the curl documentation, then I'll be happy to work on adjusting them to remove the remaining questions:

[CURLOPT_MAXCONNECTS](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_MAXCONNECTS.html) - this sets the limit when using the easy interface

[CURLMOPT_MAXCONNECTS](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLMOPT_MAXCONNECTS.html) - this is when using the multi interface

[CURLMOPT_MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLMOPT_MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS.html) - this is the maximum *live* connections

### Why 4 times the number of handles?

It was just a judgement call, an arbitrary number picked by the developers (me!) when I had to come up with a default value to use. We want to allow a connection pool of a fair size to encourage and enable good connection reuse, but we don't want it to be too large as it'll just waste resources and the larger the pool the more never-used-again connections there will be in there.

The idea also being that the multi interface typically is used with many parallel handles and therefor will use and benefit from having a larger pool/cache than the regular easy handle will, which only does transfers serially.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have still have a small question. Are connection caches still remain after we called `curl_multi_remove_handle`, right? I think the expr `data->state.conn_cache->num_connections > data->multi->num_easy * 4` can be true only if it is right.

Comment: Yes it remains. The connection cache is associated with the multi handle when using the multi interface (and the easy handle when using the easy interface) so it'll live on as long as you keep the multi handle.

Comment: I fully got it!! Thank you, great author!